# How to insert element at the beginning of a slice?

Tags: go, slice

I have a slice:

```
mySlice := []int{4,5,6,7}
myelement := 3
```

I want to insert `myelement` at index `0` so that my output will be `[3,4,5,6,7]`.

How can I do that?

Comment: `mySlice = append([]int{3}, mySlice...)`. For more see: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks

Answer (score 6):

you can use the `append` property here.

first, need to make a slice with the `myelement`. then append the slice in `mySlice`

```
mySlice = append(myelement, mySlice...)
```

this is the function that will return the `myelement` inserting in the first place of the `slice`.

```
func addElementToFirstIndex(x []int, y int) []int {
    x = append([]int{y}, x...)
    return x
}
```

[See](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks)

Answer (score 1):

```
func addFirst(s []int, insertValue int) []int {
   res := make([]int, len(s)+1)
   copy(res[1:], s)
   res[0] = insertValue
   return res
}
```

Another solution, former answers are better.